# Create a gallary Transition effect in JetPackCompose Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a list of 10 images I am showing them using **Lazygrid** Composable on the main screen and when I am clicking on a image it takes me to next screen I want to make next screen scrollable like open that image which is clicked and can swipe left and right to check other images just like we have in our phone gallary can someone tell how to do that ?

I tried this but I am unable to make this I am able to open that only a single image on the next screen

Comment: You need to use ```HorizontalPager``` in Jetpack Compose To Achieve this.